# JavaScript calling item from object with variable

Tags: javascript, object

Basically what I've got is:

```
var x= 0;
var a = "";
if (x=0) {a = "key"} else {a = "other"};
var obj = {};
obj[a] = "studentphoto";
```

x changes based on a different function, so at this point the object looks like:

```
obj = {"key":"item"};
```

now the variable x changes so when I call up the item with:

```
var j = obj.x
```

Naturally it does not work because there is no key "x" in my object.

What I would like to know is whether there is a way to have a variable that changes be the key to call up the objects item, or if I should find a better way to do it?

Comment: Are you looking for `var j = obj[a]` ? Not sure why you'd use `x` here and you already seem to know about bracket notation (`obj[a] = "studentphoto";`).

Comment: Use same concept `var j = obj[x]`

Comment: Thanks that appeared to work, i was seemingly having trouble because a was being defined in another file